# Erro ADB Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

> [2014-11-20 13:52:43 - ChegouAHora] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
>
> [2014-11-20 13:52:43 - ChegouAHora] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
>
> [2014-11-20 13:52:43 - ChegouAHora] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

---

> [2014-11-20 17:10:01 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
>
> [2014-11-20 17:10:01 - ddms] 'C:\Users\Ilgner de Oliveira\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> [2014-11-20 17:10:01 - adb] * failed to start daemon *

O meu Eclipse sempre está dando este erro, tem vez que para e depois volta, agora mesmo voltou e não consigo compilar o meu app.

Quando dou adb kill-server o resultado e * server not running *
Quando dou adb start-server o resultado e adb server is out of date. killing....
adb server didn't ack
*failed to start daemon*

Comment: Pelo que vejo por ai é restart no eclipse e restart no adb

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer estes passos:

1. Fecha o Eclipse
2. Termina o processo adb.exe no Task Manager (Windows).
3. Na linha de comandos vai a pasta do SDK do Android e ao diretório `platform-tools` .
4. Corre o comando:  `adb kill-server`
5. depois corre:  `adb start-server`
6. Se não houver mensagens de erro então o adb está a funcionar corretamente.
7. Podes abrir o Eclipse novamente.

<sup>[Fonte SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094080/1817673)</sup>

Comment: ja fiz isso e deu erro

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca lá o erro.

Comment: editei olha la ,,

Comment: Vê a minha edição.